# How can I use until in janusgraph?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

```
gremlin> a = graph.addVertex("name", "alice")
gremlin> b = graph.addVertex("name", "bobby")
gremlin> c = graph.addVertex("name", "cindy")
gremlin> d = graph.addVertex("name", "david")
gremlin> e = graph.addVertex("name", "eliza")
gremlin> a.addEdge("rates",b,"tag","ruby","value",9)
gremlin> b.addEdge("rates",c,"tag","ruby","value",8)
gremlin> c.addEdge("rates",d,"tag","ruby","value",7)
gremlin> d.addEdge("rates",e,"tag","ruby","value",6)
gremlin> e.addEdge("rates",a,"tag","java","value",9)

g.V().has('name', 'alice').repeat(out()).times(6).cyclicPath().path().by('name')
```

I want to end with alice node. and I want to repeat all the step not want to specify time as 6. The requirement is I want to get all the loop from alice or get all the loops from the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the [Cycle Detection](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#cycle-detection) section in the TinkerPop Recipes - it adapts fairly easily to your sample graph:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'alice').as('a').
......1>   repeat(out().simplePath()).
......2>     emit(loops().is(gt(1))).
......3>   both().where(eq('a')).
......4>   path().
......5>     by('name').
......6>   dedup().
......7>     by(unfold().order().dedup().fold())
==>[alice,bobby,cindy,david,eliza,alice]
```

Comment: But I also have below script.g.V().has('name','alice').repeat(out()).until(has('name','alice')).cyclicPath().limit(5).path().by('name')

Comment: But I also want to get the value of every paths. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: I will open another question for it. Would you please help me?

Comment: I have opened it just now. can you have a check?